# How to find the number of students who got full mark in all exams from the first time of taking the exams?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following part of database design where I need to find the list of students who got full mark in the popup exams from the first time of taking the exam. In details, let us assume we have three Students who took the first popup exam (Exam101) twice on different dates (or days):

```
Student A: first time, he got 0
Student A: second time, he got 10

Student B: first time, he got 10

Student C: first time, he got 10
Student C: second time, he got 0
```

***The total number of students who took all the exams and got full mark from the first time of taking it should be: 2***

The design I have for database is:

```
Students Table: StudentNo, Name, Year
Exams Table: ExamID, Title, ExamDate
StudentsExams Table: ID, ExamID, StudentNo, Score, CompletedON
```

**So who can I find this result?**

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What is a "full mark"? Is it always 10, regardless of the exam? Exams never have a potential score of 15, 20, etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a full mark is always 10 (for all exams) you can use:

```
select s.studentno,
       s.name,
       s.year,
       se.examid,
       e.title,
       se.score,
       se.completedon
  from students s
  join studentsexams se
    on s.studentno = se.studentno
  join exams e
    on se.examid = e.examid
  join (select studentno, examid, min(completedon) as first_completed
          from studentsexams
         group by studentno, examid) v
    on se.examid = v.examid
   and se.studentno = v.studentno
   and se.completedon = v.first_completed
 where se.score = 10
```

If what constitutes a "full mark" varies by exam we need to know how to determine what the max score is for each exam. Your exams table does not seem to have a max score field, based on what you posted.

Answer (score 1):

```
with cte_num
as
(
select name,ExamID,count(CompletedON)
from Students s join StudentsExams se
on s.StudentNo=se.StudentNo
join Exams e
on e.ExamID=se.ExamID
where score=10
having count(CompletedON)=1)

select count * from cte_num
```